# Access a parent's member

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given the following code:

```
            self.pcsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(pcs, function (pc) {
                return {
                    obCurHp: ko.observable(pc.curHp), obMaxHp: ko.observable(pc.hp), 
                    obHpPerc: ko.computed(function(){return Math.round(this.obCurHp() / this.obMaxHp())*100 + "%";})
                };
            }));
```

obHpPrec does not evaluate to anything because neither `this.obCurHp()` & `this.obMaxHp()` are a thing nor are `obCurHp()` & `obMaxHp()`.

I need to access these members of the current pcsList object so I can construct the computed object. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep `this` in each context separate. You can have a sub model  and just create a new instance for each element.

```
var mainViewModel = function (){
   var self = this;
   self.pcsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(pcs, function (pc) {
      return new pcListItemViewModel(pc);
   }));
}
var pcListItemViewModel = function (pc){
   var self = this;
   self.obCurHp =  ko.observable(pc.curHp);
   self.obMaxHp =  ko.observable(pc.hp); 
   self.obHpPerc = ko.computed(function(){
      return Math.round(self.obCurHp() / self.obMaxHp())*100 + "%";
   });
}
```

Comment: decided that i didnt need `obHpPrec` to be a computed observable so I just made just another function. Since my `obCurHp` and `obMaxHp` are observables, the function updates the percentages just fine. Though this is a good thing to keep in mind thanks!